# Is there a way to make a parent adopt a property/variable form the child? c#

Tags: c#, parent-child, parent

like the title asks, is there some way to make the Parent of a Child adopt a property, or variable, from the child? I need to make a counter that keeps track of the amount of times a button is pressend in the child, but the counter itself needs to be in the parent.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what type parent and child are. Maybe the child could raise an event which the parent could handle...

Comment: If the Child belongs to the Parent, can you not access the child property from the Parents collection of children? E.g. Parent.Children[0].ButtonPressedCount

Comment: The parent is a form in visual studio, while the child is a button class, although it may be the other way around, i'm not quite sure

Comment: You need to raise an event then from the child to the parent form.

Comment: And how do i do that?